# unable to retrieve feeds using jFeed

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to display rss feed using jQuery plugin jFeed as below. It's printing alert('ok') but it's not displaying feed title         `alert(feed.title);`

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="javascript/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="javascript/jquery.jfeed.js"></script>



<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
alert('ok');
$.getFeed({
    url: 'http://feeds.nytimes.com/nyt/rss/Technology',
    success: function(feed) {
        alert(feed.title);
    }
});

});

</script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="main">

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not load external feeds (*from different domains than the calling page*).

Quote from the plugin page

> Examples are provided in the archive,
>   **as well as a basic PHP proxy (testing
>   purposes only) for loading external
>   feeds.**

There is a ***proxy.php*** file in the bundle.

Use it.

---

To use the provided proxy you need to do

```
$.getFeed({
    url: '/local-path-to-proxy/proxy.php',
    data: {url:'http://feeds.nytimes.com/nyt/rss/Technology'},
    success: function(feed) {
        alert(feed.title);
    }
});
```

(*adjust the path to the proxy file accordingly*)

Comment: With that proxy.php can we get the feeds from different domains.

Comment: @Sukumar, yes. That is the point of the proxy. Browsers do not allow cross-domain ajax requests (*unless the format is JSONP*). But you can use a server side technology (*like php in this case*) to bring the data from the remote location and feed it to out ajax request. Example of usage in updated answer.

Comment: thanks a lot. Now i got it. It's displaying alert window but not displaying any thing. Is there any thing blocking in browser.

Comment: @Sukumar, can you put it somewhere live ? Or you can use firebug to see what the ajax call returns..